# Append select option with an HTML5 data attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to construct a set of options for a select element, using jQuery. It's working except for the data attribute that should be included, which seems to being ommitted.

Here is my code:

```
// cJ is JSON object.
// #currency is my select element.
function makeCurDropDown(cJ) {
    $.each(cJ, function (i) {
        $('#currency').append(
            $('<option></option>').val(i).data("sym", cJ[i][0]).html(cJ[i][1])
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the `data` is set, but since you are using `data` method instead of the `attr` method, it's not visible. jQuery stores the value behind the scenes, for getting the value you can use `.data('sym')`. If you want to set the value as an attribute you can use `attr` method instead.

Comment: I got it!

`$('<option></option>').val(i).attr("data-sym", cJ[i][0]).html(cJ[i][1])`

Thanks.

Comment: Smartly answered Undefined